# C++ OpenCV Kalman filter constructor error

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I've implemented OpenCV's Kalman filter in a previous C++ project and I am now trying to use it in the context of a class.

This is how I usually construct my Kalman filter:

`cv::KalmanFilter KF(4,2,0);`

I am now trying to have the filter as a member of a class and I'm having trouble initialising it.

I have tried:

## 1)

```
class foo
{
public:
...
private:
  cv::KalmanFilter m_filter(4,2,0);
};
```

And I get the following error:

`error: expected identifier before numeric constant
             cv::KalmanFilter m_filter(4,2,0);
                                       ^
foo.hpp:31:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant`

## 2)

If I try to remove the initialisation there and do it in the class constructor with:

#### .hpp

```
...
private:
  cv::KalmanFilter m_filter;
```

#### .cpp

```
constructor(...)
{
  m_filter(4,2,0);
}
```

I get:

`error: no match for call to ‘(cv::KalmanFilter) (int, int, int)’
     m_filter(4,2,0);
                   ^`

Comment: you can simply do `constructor(...) : m_filter(4,2,0) {...}`

Comment: Do you happen to release m_filter anywhere? Say, in `foo`'s destructor.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Your method works, thanks!

Comment: I don't release m_filter, should I?

Comment: No, you should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around with cv::KalmanFilter's constructor, the code finally compiles with the following private declaration:

```
...
private:
        cv::KalmanFilter m_filter{cv::KalmanFilter(4,2,0)};
```